# list all files in a folder and sub folder without extention

Tags: vbscript

I've come across the following script that I'd really like to use but I would like it not to have the .extention at the end

```
Dim fso
Dim ObjOutFile

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set ObjOutFile = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\User\Movies.csv")

ObjOutFile.WriteLine("Type,File Name,Size")

GetFiles("E:\")

ObjOutFile.Close

Function GetFiles(FolderName)
    On Error Resume Next

    Dim ObjFolder
    Dim ObjSubFolders
    Dim ObjSubFolder
    Dim ObjFiles
    Dim ObjFile

    Set ObjFolder = fso.GetFolder(FolderName)
    Set ObjFiles = objfolder.Files

    For Each ObjFile In ObjFiles
    ObjOutFile.WriteLine("File," & ObjFile.Name & "," & objFile.Size & "," & objFile.Type)
    Next

    Set ObjSubFolders = ObjFolder.SubFolders

    For Each ObjFolder In ObjSubFolders

        ObjOutFile.WriteLine("Folder," & ObjFolder.Name)


        GetFiles(ObjFolder.Path)
    Next

End Function
```

I'm rubbish at this but I would really apperciate the help

Answer (score 1):

Use the [.GetBaseName()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhxzwwe1(v=vs.84).aspx) method of the FileSystemObject. As in:

```
>> WScript.Echo goFS.GetBaseName("c:\dir\name.ext")
>>
name
```

Comment: Sorry, where do I use that in the above script